# Definition of the word "festgefaßten"

Tags: meaning

From Schopenhauer's Über die Weiber:

> Aus der selben Quelle ist es abzuleiten, daß die Weiber mehr Mitleid und daher mehr Menschenliebe und Theilnahme an Unglücklichen zeigen, als die Männer; hingegen im Punkte der Gerechtigkeit, Redlichkeit und Gewissenhaftigkeit, diesen nachstehn. Denn in Folge ihrer schwachen Vernunft übt das Gegenwärtige, Anschauliche, unmittelbar Reale eine Gewalt über sie aus, gegen welche die abstrakten Gedanken, die stehenden Maximen, die ***festgefaßten*** Entschlüsse, überhaupt die Rücksicht auf Vergangenheit und Zukunft, auf Abwesendes und Entferntes, selten viel vermögen.

In looking for it on google, I found other instances of this word, especially in old books, but no definition whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nur ein wirklich **fest gefasster** Entschluss verhindert, dass Sie kurz vor Erreichen Ihres Ziels doch noch einen Rückzieher machen und sich anders entscheiden.

Only a **truly determined** decision prevents you from taking a step backwards and making a difference before you reach your goal.

new German spelling for "**festgefaßten**".

Answer (score 1):

> - den Entschluss zu etwas fassen = sich zu etwas entschließen = *to
>   decide to do something*
> - den festen Entschluss zu etwas fassen = sich zu etwas fest
>   entschließen = *to decide firmly to do something*
> - ein fest gefasster Entschluss = *a firm/determined decision*
> - fest gefasste Entschlüsse = *firm/determined decisions*

<sub>I don't claim the English translations to be perfect.</sub>

As already told Schopenhauer is using the obsolete spelling *»festgefaßten«*.